# Take hexadecimal number as input?

Tags: ruby, input, hex

How can I take a hexadecimal number as input? I don't mean to take an integer as input and convert it to hexadecimal, but to take a hexadecimal number as input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To read a hex number from standard input and parse: `gets.to_i(16)`.  I think what you really meant to ask was how to do this:

```
x = gets.to_i(16)
x = x + 1
puts x.to_s(16)
```

Ruby defaults all parsing/printing to decimal; you have to be explicit if you want hex.

Comment: or you could call gets.hex as a shortcut

Comment: that will covert the integer to hexadecimal and assign to the variable...i don't need that

Comment: That's actually not true.  This will read a hexadecimal string from standard input, convert it to an integer.  You can then display that integer however you'd like: `puts gets.to_i(16)` will read hex, but print decimal. `puts gets.to_i(16).to_s(8)` will convert hex to octal, and so forth...

Comment: try this
a = gets.to_i(16)
puts a+1

It will output 10..its supposed to give A

Comment: That's correct, when you print the result, you have to specify you want it in hex: `puts (a+1).to_s(16)`.  Ruby does not store any 'base' information about the variable.  A Number is a number.  You only specify base when converting to/from String.

Answer (score 2):

This?

```
>> "0xfa".hex
=> 250
```

Or this?

```
>> ((0x4009)+1).to_s(16)
=> "400a"
```

Comment: then you may try to clarify the question (pairs of input/expected output)

Comment: 4009 or "4009"? because 4009 (integer) has no base, its representation (usually a string) does have to choose a base.

Comment: thnx tokland for your time...see previous comments i got it

Comment: you are confused, integers have no base, only representation of integers need to choose a base. What you actually need is the contrary you are asking for: ((0x4009)+1).to_s(16)